# get data from a single table of crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have two tables A and B. I need to calculate records on the basis of one filter (for ex : date = 01/13/2014) , which is present in table B and not in table A.

Now i have to display records in report which is (total records from table A without joining with Table B - records with filter criteria date in which both table A and table B are joined)?

I have tried it but it is not possible from my side because once i put two tables in crystal report it is asking for a join.

How can i do it please suggest

Comment: not sure if I understand your question correctly but you could probably solve this problem using a sub-report. Can you do a SQL fiddle of your data and post so that is easier to see what you mean.

Comment: @SOfanatic      select * from ((select vw.*
FROM DSPRD.VW_MAIN vw
WHERE EVT_ORG = 'A')
minus 
(select vw.*
FROM DSPRD.VW_MAIN vw inner JOIN DSPRD.r5propertyvalues rv
ON vw.EVT_CODE = rv.PRV_CODE
WHERE EVT_ORG = 'A'  and
(prv_property = 'WOSCPRI') and (prv_value = '1' or prv_value = '2')));   where prv_property and prv value are from table r5propertyvalues

Comment: the SQL fiddle refers to a simplified version of your DB schema and some test data. You should include what your data looks like and what you want the output to be. Look into this site: http://sqlfiddle.com/